# conditional input list shiny r

Tags: r, shiny

Imagine I've the following example, where I select one of three numbers, and than I have a selectlist with the number I choose plus 1, 2 and 3 if it is 1, or I have the number plus 10, 11 or 12, otherwise.

I'm having troubles when I try to use the input.sel as a variable, can someone explain why it is ok in the condition but it is not ok to use it as a variable?

```
conditionalPanel("input.sidebarmenu === 'dashboard8'",
                        selectInput("sel", "Select:", c(1,2,3), selected = "1"),

    conditionalPanel(
         condition = "input.sel == '1'",
         selectInput("Role1", "Role:", c(input.sel+10,input.sel+11,input.sel+12 ), selected = "All")),
    conditionalPanel(
         condition = "input.sel != '1'",
         selectInput("Role2", "Role:", c(input.sel+1,input.sel+2,input.sel+3) , selected = "All")                            
),
```

Comment: You have this variables only on server side, Or you nee to use JS to get variable.( coindition uses JS to do it )

Comment: ok, it makes sense, but can you tell me how please?

Comment: Use `renderUI` or `updateSelectInput` on the server side to dynamically render/update the select input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like  :

In UI

```
selectInput("Role1", "Role:", "", selected = ""))
```

and in Server

```
observe({
updateSelectInput(session,"Role1",choices=input$sel+10:12,selected= input$sel+10:12))
})
```

or better `observeEvent(input$sel,...)` to change input only when `sel` changed

Comment: and what session stands for? I got the following warning: Warning: Error in updateSelectInput: object 'session' not found

Comment: Add session to your server function `shinyServer(function(input, output, session)`